# How to increse numbers from 00000 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to increase numbers from 00000 to 99999. I tried, but it is not working. Below is my code:

```
    $result=mysql_query("select rid from regid") or die (mysql_error("No Record Found"));
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                extract($row);

                $sub=substr("$rid",15);  //It is substring 00000 coming from database. 

            $n2 = str_pad($sub + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);  // It is code line.
        echo $n2;
        }
```

Comment: - How to multiply by a million? - Append 6 zeros. - I tried, it does not work :)

Comment: I want 00000,000001, 000002-------99999

Comment: what values do you have in `rid`?

Comment: What's the result you get by this?

Comment: 00000 is in database, which is coming with rid. Further i will insert it in database like 00000, 000001, 000002.....00010,....99999 through insert query.

Comment: Its working... $sub=substr("$rid",15); ned to remove.

Comment: thnx to all masters

Comment: Increasing a number with leading zeros is simple, the question is why is MySQL involved in the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Add increment as follows

```
 $i = 0;
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    extract($row);

                    $sub=substr("$rid",15);  //It is substring 00000 coming from database. 

                $n2 = str_pad($sub + $i, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);  // It is code line.
            echo $n2;
   $i++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another loop increasing i +1 until 99999.

```
  $result=mysql_query("select rid from regid") or die (mysql_error("No Record Found"));
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    extract($row);

            $sub=substr("$rid",15);  //It is substring 00000 coming from database. 
        }
$i = 0;
while ($i<100000)
{
  $n2 = str_pad($sub + $i, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);  
        echo $n2;
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you

```
$number = str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

demo : https://3v4l.org/aYZUk

Answer (score 0):

The database can do it direct for you use **zerofill**. if you create a table like this (or change your own). With the length from int you can say how much digits you want :

```
MariaDB [YourSchema]> show create table yourCount;
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| yourCount | CREATE TABLE `yourCount` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myDate` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [YourSchema]>
```

**Sample - show data**

```
MariaDB [YourSchema]> select * from yourCount;
+--------+--------+
| id     | myDate |
+--------+--------+
| 000001 | data1  |
| 000002 | data2  |
| 000003 | data3  |
+--------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Insert new row without count**

```
MariaDB [YourSchema]> insert into yourCount (myDate) VALUES ('data4');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)


MariaDB [YourSchema]> select * from yourCount;
+--------+--------+
| id     | myDate |
+--------+--------+
| 000001 | data1  |
| 000002 | data2  |
| 000003 | data3  |
| 000004 | data4  |
+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**add row with id**

```
MariaDB [YourSchema]> insert into yourCount (id,myDate) VALUES (5,'data4');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [YourSchema]> select * from yourCount;
+--------+--------+
| id     | myDate |
+--------+--------+
| 000001 | data1  |
| 000002 | data2  |
| 000003 | data3  |
| 000004 | data4  |
| 000005 | data4  |
+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```